# Simple software to plot satellites' orbits?

Tags: artificial-satellite, software

I want to build a simple personal project, a software that allows users to choose between 5 or 6 satellites, then draw the chosen satellite's path on a google map. But I really don't know where to start.

I thought about targeting communication satellites only -due to their fixed locations-, but I cannot figure out the ground tracking. is there an equation or anything similar to concluded and predict where the satellite would be with respect to earth's rotation, and thus draw its full path ?

Comment: Please let us know what celestial mechanics books you have already read. Reference: https://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/249/resources-and-references-considered-as-literary-canons-on-the-topic-of-interpl

Comment: @DeerHunter , none ; I'm a programmer -Computer Science degree-. All my info on astronomy comes from documentaries.

Comment: No single equation can help you here. You have to start reading - Bate, Mueller and White is a good start.

Comment: Please also note that communications satellites **do not** have fixed locations.

Comment: @DeerHunter , thank you for the sources you provided and for answering ; it would sure come in handy. I'll do more reading & research then try my hand with this project.

Comment: You may use [ready to use libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellite_pass_predictors#Software_libraries), but a good background of celestial mechanics is still recommended to use them. The link is just one of many possibilities.

Comment: @mins , many thanks ! I neglected the importance of APIs that help in this . OreKit sounds like a good option -documentation+tutorials-, but still I need to do lots of reading in celestial mechanics and astronomy in general to write a logical code :D thanks again